# editable Text window with wx in Python

Tags: python, wxpython

I need to create a window for showing text in multiple line(like notepad.below is my application).I create a wx.TextCtrl using wxPython Problem is it can't print in multiple lines even if you put \n at end of your strings.What should I use? I couldn't find wxPython documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the wx.TE_MULTILINE style for your textctrl, e.g.

```
text = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
```

Comment: How can I make it multistyle ? for instance both vertical Scrollable and multiline?

Comment: It seems it already became vertically scrollable with multiline.Thanks!

Comment: You can combine styles using the | operator (wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER). Have a look at http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_text_ctrl.html to see the styles you can use (plus those of the base wxWindow). Vertical scroll is on by default.

Comment: How is it possible to have option of printing each line with different font color?ForgroundColor changes all other lines with new color which is not desired..